# Hint system in Google Docs

Tags: google-docs

Is there any way to integrate hint machinery similar to the one used on puzzling.stackexchange.com inside a Google Docs?

That is, I want that hidden text is revealed after a certain user request (as a mouse hovering).

The optimum would be to record and store such requests.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to `>!` (Markdown that is also available to Web Applications by the way) in my opinion would be to use a font colour the same as the background:

[image: WA110795 example]

At the top is the normal view and below that after selection.